# can I create many different indexed ImageViews using the same background? (android)

Tags: java, android

I'm making some sort of orb-dodging game and I want to create many different orbs. usually, to create an Image\button\whatever I make a single thing in the XML and assign it to an object on the java code. it does work well when there are a few objects but can I make an essentially unlimited amount of orbs using a single picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML was introduced at the beginning of Android for "easier" layouting (it turned out it wasn't so much, got own problems, currently new approaches are more popular), but all of its possibilities can be achieved with code. e.g. creation of new `TextView` instead of `findViewById` form XML: `textView = new TextView(this);` (`this` for `Activity`, if you are in `Fragment` just use `requireContext()` instead)

remember that `View`s created this way won't appear on the screen, they must be added to `Activity`s/`Fragment`s layout (using `setContentView` or `onCreateView` respectively)

btw. making a game using "unlimited amount" of Android framework `View`s is a very bad idea, you will get VERY poor performance... at least use [`Canvas` drawing](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing)

Comment: Will try later. What makes the "unlimited amount" thing such a bad idea? Is it because it takes resources when not used or is it just when the frameworks are used?

Comment: each `View` needs `Context` and must be measured before drawn, thats pretty heavyoperation. then moving these views on the screen is yet another expensive operation. you will notice difference with even few dozens of `View`s, so "unlimited ammount" will eat your memory entirely in a sec